# Simulating producer errors on azure event hubs using spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, azure-eventhub

I am using a spring cloud stream Kafka binder based producer and consumer Below is my producer configuration , I would like to receive an error upon sending messages to eventhub and channel that to an error channel . Not sure how under what scenario does event hub throw an error on the producer end and channel it to an error channel

```
server.port: 9876
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: test
      kafka:
        bindings:
          output:
            producer:
         
              retries: 3
              sync: false
        binder:
          configuration:
            request:
              timeout:
                ms: 60000
            security:
              protocol: SASL_SSL
            sasl:
              mechanism: PLAIN
              jaas:
                config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="<Pwd>";
          brokers: <Broker URL>
          autoCreateTopics: false
          producer-properties:
            acks: all
```

Comment: Did you try writing a producer and simply throw a new IllegalStateException or something similar to see what happens?